# SMS Personalization using AMPScript in Salesforce Marketing Cloud

Tags: javascript, salesforce, ampscript

My CRM team is running into problems when attempting to personalize SMS using AMPScript. The syntax used is as follows:

```
%%[
Var @subscriberKey 
Set @subscriberKey = _subscriberKey 
]%%

%%= v(@subscriberKey) =%%
```

Thank you for signing up for a 45 day risk-free hearing aid trial! One of our expert hearing consultants will call you soon to discuss next steps. During this call, we'll discuss your hearing loss situation and go over the details of the 45 day risk-free trial. We look forward to speaking with you shortly!

I have created a data extension in Marketing Cloud with just me in it, and used it on a journey that sends a text message with this content to my phone. The text message delivers, however the personalization content is not in there, just the plain text is shown. Of course, once the personalization works, we will change it so that other information is in there and not subscriberKey, but for now it would be a ton of help to know why the syntax is not working when it should.

Kind regards,
Michael

Comment: You'll get a lot more eyes on your SFMC questions over at [salesforce.stackexchange.com](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com), specifically with the [marketing-cloud](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marketing-cloud) and [ampscript](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ampscript) tags.

Answer (score 0):

you will need to add the personalized field i.e. First Name/ Subscriber Key/etc in the following format %%FirstName%% . This field is actually picked up from the Attributed which are linked in your Contact Builder. Look for Mobile Connect Demographics, make sure these attributes which are trying to add in personalization are present there. 
Now next step is how to link your information from your Master DE to the MobileConnect Demographics, for that u need to create an Import Activity from Contact Builder, and Import these details in a Mobile Connect List.

Hope this helps.
Mobile Connect Lists are different from Emails Studio Lists - Keep this in mind.